# On hover, move the navigation's icon from current page item to the hovering

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, hover, css-transitions

I'm currently creating a navigation. So far, I have a bg-image for the hover/current-page item which just appears on hover/when the site is active.

But now, I want to advance it and add a nice transition effect to it. The idea was to move the icon of the current page item towards the hovering element.

[image]

So, if you are on start and hover over 'Vertrieb' the pointer above the text should move to Vertrieb.

If you are on 'referenzen' and move towards 'blog' or 'über mich' it should move towards it.

[image]

Any Ideas? I already made a lot of navigations with text-transition, but this is way over my skill level.

PS: Here's the markup:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" title="Start" class="current_page_item">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" title="Über mich">Über mich</a></li>
    <li><a href="philosophie.html" title="Philosophie">Philosophie</a></li>
    <li><a href="referenzen.html" title="Referenzen">Referenzen</a></li>
    <li><a href="vertrieb.html" title="Vertrieb">Vertrieb</a></li>
    <li><a href="coaching.html" title="Coaching">Coaching</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="blog.html" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>




ul.nav { 
    position: relative; 
    float: right;
    margin: 28px 10px 0 0;
    }   

ul.nav li { 
    padding: 0 20px 0 0; 
    float: left; 
    list-style: none;
    }

ul.nav li a { 
    display: block; 
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 0.9375em;
    -webkit-transition-property:color, text, background; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in; 
    -moz-transition-property:color, text; 
    -moz-transition-duration:0.25s; 
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;  
    -o-transition-property:color, text; 
    -o-transition-duration:0.25s; 
    -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
    }

ul.nav li a:hover,
ul.nav li a:focus,
ul.nav li a.current_page_item { 
    color: #e86228; 
    background: url(images/nav_pointer.png) no-repeat top;
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: The internet crawls with demos on this topic, even in pure CSS. Do more research ;)

Comment: @Allendar Hey, I searched for hours, on German and English. Since I'm not an english mothertongue speaker I'm not sure what I got to search after and probably missed it. Can you give me a keyword?

Comment: @user1479606 I'm looking for the code, I don't have it. Except basic html/css markup.

Comment: Put your HTML/CSS markup in the question and I'll show you some tips and tricks.

Comment: @Allendar Posted the markup

Comment: I won't post it as an answer, cause I've got a lazy day and did it with jQuery anyway :P http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/CwnFt/. Happy coding :)

Comment: Jeez, thank you! That looks good! :) It's not possible without jQuery, is it? I'd accept it, but I can't accept comments, only answers. :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28004/discussion-between-shawnwhite-and-allendar)

Comment: Transcribed it as an answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transcribed from the comments;

[JSfiddle (example with jQuery)](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/CwnFt)

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu_wrap {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#nav li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#arrow {
    background-image: url('http://www.jukti.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/google_pointer_map.png');
    background-size: 25px 35px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li').mouseover(function() {
        var pos = $(this)[0].offsetLeft;
        pos = pos + Math.floor((($(this).css('width').replace('px', '') * 1) / 2));
        pos = pos - Math.floor(($('#arrow').css('width').replace('px', '') * 1) / 2)

        // Reset all colors
        $('#nav li a').css('color', '#444');

        // Animte the arrow
        $('#arrow').animate({
            'margin-left': pos + 'px'
        }, 250);

        // Change the color
        $('a', this).css('color', 'orange');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Except one thing. I changed a few parameters, everything works fine, but is it possible to have it's starting position on the current_page_item?

Comment: Tweaked the initial setting of the with/without the class being present and to set the initial color correctly; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/CwnFt/32/

Comment: Hey, this doesn't change it. I googled for another round and one guy said it might hang together with the mouseover, which also lets the pointer/effect stay at the last hovered position instead of going back. I'm currently trying to figure it out for the sake or learning how to a) have current_page_item as starting element and b) having it going back to current_page_item as soon as I leave the hover. Thanks for your help, **Allendar!**

Comment: What browser are you using? The JavaScript is super basic, it shouldn't behave differently in other browsers. Check my last example (number 32).

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome. I'll check it and call you back when I tried it and googled a bit more! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, neither your last fiddle nor my search results worked. I tried play around with .stop and .mouseleave, but it didn't work. I also tried to use .hover instead on mouseover, but this won't work as well. Thanks, I keep on trying to figure it out how to fix it.

Comment: I think you're breaking it. That what you say isnt needed at all. Can you post your fiddle?

Comment: I undo'd all my actions, so I'm currently working with your 32 fiddle and some minor changes like text-color & id's/classes. http://jsfiddle.net/DzW88/5/

Comment: You messed up the CSS and JS a bit, which made the dynamic coloring of the a-tags go bad. It's fixed now; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/DzW88/6/. I'll be in the chatroom for further assistance :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28004/discussion-between-shawnwhite-and-allendar